# Spring Boot tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar: zip file is empty

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I have simple Springboot application, but whenever I try to run the app
I get following error, I have tried mvn clean install, also tried reimports and `Generate Sources and Update Folder options`

````
/Users/a0r00rf/Downloads/SpringStartedCRUD/demoCRUD/src/main/java/com/abhimanyu/demoCRUD/com/abhimanyu/demoCRUD/com/abhimanyu/demoCRUD/services/EmployeeServiceImpl.java
Error:(1, 1) java: cannot access com.abhimanyu.demoCRUD.com.abhimanyu.demoCRUD.com.abhimanyu.demoCRUD.services
Error reading file /Users/a0r00rf/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar: zip file is empty
/Users/a0r00rf/Downloads/SpringStartedCRUD/demoCRUD/src/main/java/com/abhimanyu/demoCRUD/com/abhimanyu/demoCRUD/com/abhimanyu/demoCRUD/services/EmployeeService.java
Error:(1, 1) java: cannot access com.abhimanyu.demoCRUD.com.abhimanyu.demoCRUD.com.abhimanyu.demoCRUD
Error reading file /Users/a0r00rf/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar: zip file is empty
Error:(7, 8) java: cannot access java.lang
Error reading file /Users/a0r00rf/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar: zip file is empty ```
````

Comment: How do you run this application ? Can you show the location of this project in gihub ?

Comment: show more detail about your pom.xml

Comment: Were you able to solve this error ? I am also facing the same issue !

Answer (score 21):

Find Tomcat under `.m2/repository`, remove it and `mvn install` again.

Comment: You can quickly find and remove empty jars with `find $HOME/.m2/repository -iname "*.jar" -size 0 -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Saved hrs of debugging, Worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when a few of yours particular dependency could not be downloaded properly. For this the cure is to go to $HOME/.m2/ and delete this folder.

This deletes all the dependencies installed. Then select invalidate Cache and restart from File in the topmost toolbar in IntellJ.

Then select your POM.xml file, right click and reload dependencies

It will download dependencies, index them and Boom it will work